InAppBrowser not fullscreen
I can't get inAppBrowser to be fullscreen
Here are my preferences
 <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
 <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />

Once app us ready, I hide the statusbar, then open inAppBrowser
    StatusBar.hide();

    var url = 'https://cordova.apache.org';
    var target = "_blank";
    var options = "location=yes,hideurlbar=yes,hidden=yes,beforeload=no,fullscreen=yes";
    browser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
    browser.show();

The inAppBrowser is not going fullscreen, what am I missing?

